# image slide show using tkinter and ImageTk

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, python-3.7

i am trying to make an image slide show but i cant get the ImageTk module to work

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
from ImageTk import PhotoImage

images = ["ffa1c83.jpg", "ffa4600.jpg", "faa4149.jpg", "f099e64.png"]
photos = cycle(PhotoImage(file=image) for image in images)

def slideShow():
  img = next(photos)
  displayCanvas.config(image=img)
  root.after(50, slideShow) # 0.05 seconds

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (640, 480))
displayCanvas = tk.Label(root)
displayCanvas.pack()
root.after(10, lambda: slideShow())
root.mainloop()
```

i am using python 3.7

i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cj\Desktop\code_stuff\slideshow\slide show V2\SlideShowV2.py", 
line 3, in <module>
    from ImageTk import PhotoImage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ImageTk'
```

Comment: `ImageTk` is part of module `PIL`/`pillow` - use `from PIL import ImageTk, Image`

Comment: @furas i tried that and got the exact same error code

Comment: did you remove `from ImageTk import PhotoImage` ?

Comment: you have to remove `from ImageTk import PhotoImage` and use `from PIL import ImageTk, Image` and then you will have to use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))` .

Comment: because you have to use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))`

Comment: @furas where do i put `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))` ?
i am very new to this kind of thing.

Comment: you put it instead of `PhotoImage(file=image)`

Comment: BTW: in `after()` you have to use function's name without `()` - `after(10, slideShow)` - it is so called "callback" and you use it also in `tk.Button(comman=callback)`  and `widget.bind(event, callback, arg)`

Comment: i got a very large error
here is a screen shot since i cant paste the whole thing : https://ibb.co/BBGzPFr
also: i dont understand what you mean by that

Comment: you used wrong variable. it should be `image` instead of `images` in `Image.open(image)`

Comment: its working now, thanks for the help and being patient with my minimal knowledge!

Comment: and read about bug in PhotoImage - it is common problem when you load image but it doesn't show in window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageTk` is part of module `PIL`/`pillow`

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```

`ImageTk.PhotoImage` is used instead of standard `tkinter.PhotoImage` which can't read `.png`.

In older versions `tkinter.PhotoImage` couldn't read `.jpg` and it was working only with `.gif`.

---

Minimal code

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
from PIL import ImageTk

images = ["ffa1c83.jpg", "ffa4600.jpg", "faa4149.jpg", "f099e64.png"]
photos = cycle(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=image) for image in images)
```

---

**BTW:** Read about bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable in function - see `Note` in doc [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)